# Ao clicar no botão para chamar função javaScript o botão sume

Tags: javascript, números-aleatórios

Estou tentando fazer um código para gerar número aleatório em javaScript, coloquei um botão para poder chamar a função, chama a função corretamente, entretanto tenho que atualizar a página para poder visualizar o botão, gostaria de deixar o botão fixo sem precisar atualizar a tela, mas não está dando certo.
Segue o código

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Numero aleatorio</title>
</head>

<body>
<script>
function Mudarestado(el){
document.getElementById("minhaDiv").innerHTML = 'limite';

limite = 5;
n = parseInt(Math.random()*limite); // limite não incluso
tabela = '<table border=1>';
tabela +='<tr>';
tabela +='<td>Numero Sorteado: </td>';
tabela +='<td>'+n+'</td>';
tabela +='</tr>';
tabela +='</table><br><br>';
document.write(tabela);

document.write('Frutas: ('+n+')')
if (n==5){
document.write('Numero 5 foi sorteado!!!')
}


}

</script><br><br>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $("#minhaDiv").hide();

        $("#nav-button").click(function (e) {
            $("#minhaDiv").toggle();
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="minhaDiv">
<button type="button" id="nav-button" onclick="Mudarestado('minhaDiv')">Sortear número</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>



    
        <html>
        <head>
         <title>Joao e Maria</title>
        </head>
    
        <body>
        <script>
        function Mudarestado(el){
        document.getElementById("minhaDiv").innerHTML = 'limite';
    
        limite = 5;
        n = parseInt(Math.random()*limite); // limite não incluso
        tabela = '<table border=1>';
        tabela +='<tr>';
        tabela +='<td>Numero Sorteado: </td>';
        tabela +='<td>'+n+'</td>';
        tabela +='</tr>';
        tabela +='</table><br><br>';
        document.write(tabela);
    
        document.write('Frutas: ('+n+')')
        if (n==5){
        document.write('Numero 5 foi sorteado!!!')
        }
    
    
        }
    
        </script><br><br>
    
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function (e) {
                $("#minhaDiv").hide();
    
                $("#nav-button").click(function (e) {
                    $("#minhaDiv").toggle();
                });
            });
        </script>
    
        <div id="minhaDiv">
        <button type="button" id="nav-button" onclick="Mudarestado('minhaDiv')">Sortear número</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando usa [`document.write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) ele sobrescreve o conteúdo da página, por isso seu botão some.

Crie um `div` para receber o resultado e então modifique a propriedade [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) para mudar o conteúdo do `div`.

```html
    
<html>
    <head>
     <title>Numero aleatório</title>
    </head>

<body>
    <script>
    function Mudarestado(el){
    

      limite = 5;
      document.getElementById("resultadoDiv").innerHTML = 'limite = ' + limite ;
      n = parseInt(Math.random()*limite); // limite não incluso
      tabela = '<table border=1>';
      tabela +='<tr>';
      tabela +='<td>Numero Sorteado: </td>';
      tabela +='<td>'+n+'</td>';
      tabela +='</tr>';
      tabela +='</table><br><br>';
      document.getElementById("resultadoDiv").innerHTML += tabela;
    
      document.getElementById("resultadoDiv").innerHTML += 'Frutas: ('+n+')';
      if (n==5){
        document.getElementById("resultadoDiv").innerHTML += 'Numero 5 foi sorteado!!!';
      }


    }

    </script><br><br>



    <div id="minhaDiv">
    <button type="button" id="nav-button" onclick="Mudarestado('minhaDiv')">Sortear número</button>
    </div>
    
    <div id="resultadoDiv">
       Sorteio
    </div>
    

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Você não está atualizando a tela. Esse efeito se dá já que você está utilizando o `document.write` para escrever na tela.

O funcionamento do `document.write` é simples: basicamente, enquanto a página está carregando, ele insere o conteúdo normalmente sem alterar o restante da página. **No entanto, se o documento já foi 100% carregado, quando o `document.write` for invocado, todo o conteúdo da página será substituído pelo conteúdo que você passou como argumento para esse método.** [Você pode saber mais sobre essa API aqui.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write)

Então, para resolver isso, você tem que usar algo além do `document.write`. Vamos usar a técnica de criar um novo elemento e em seguida inseri-lo ao final da página.

Algo assim:

```js
function sortNum() {
  // Gera um número aleatório no intervalo 0~99:
  const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
  
  // Cria um elemento <div>:
  const div = document.createElement('div')
  
  // Adiciona o número escolhido como texto da <div>:
  div.textContent = random
  
  // Adiciona (append) a <div> criada ao final do <body>:
  document.body.appendChild(div)
}
```

```html
<button id="my-button" onclick="sortNum()">Sortear um Número</button>
```